# Nginx force unsecure connection

Tags: nginx, neo4j

I have Neo4j running behind Nginx.  Everything was fine until I altered the configuration of Nginx to use SSL.  All my other services work (on their unsecured port 80s), but Neo4j now insists (on its login page) that I use 'bolt+s' or 'neo4j+s' secure connection schemes.  I've tried adding `proxy_ssl off` to the block to force an unsecured connection for bolt, but it doesn't work.

How can I force Nginx (listening in ssl mode) to connect to Neo4j (or another network service) in http/unsecure mode?

Answer (score 1):

You could configure a reverse proxy with [proxy_pass](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass). Ensure it starts with the `http` protocol.

Comment: Oddly enough the issue occurs even though I've done that.  It works fine for the other services behind the proxy (it passes http as intended).  Must be that Neo4j is guessing that https is in use from some clue in a header or something, passed from nginx.

Comment: I do need to look at the headers, that's one thing I haven't tried.  I am specifying the http/bolt ports (though bolt can upgrade anyway).  Thank you for your input!